# An Issue Related To VLC

Tags: video, vlc

Each time I close VLC Player after watching a video file, I get these messages one after another:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vLnz.png]

After pressing `Continue`, I get an another message:

[image: ehttps://i.stack.imgur.com/XIeNm.png]

I don't get these messages after playing an audio file in it. Despite these messages, VLC continue to work fine on my computer.

Is it something I should bother about?

My OS: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS - 32-bit; 
VLC: Media Player 2.0.8 Twoflower

Comment: I've been asked to update VLC by VLC forum. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

For the question you asked your comment (I think it is what you want to do), you can run these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/stable-daily
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Comment: What these commands do?